# Parameter object slows down program significantly in C

Tags: c, performance, gcc, design-patterns, struct

I have a bunch of related arrays `arr1, arr2, arr3`. I pass these to a few functions, like `foo`.

```c
int foo(int* arr1, int* arr2, int* arr3, ...) { ... }
```

The argument list starts to get pretty long, so I wanted to make a struct `Bar` to collect these related arrays in a single struct, like so:

```c
struct Bar {
    int* arr1;
    int* arr2;
    int* arr3;
};
```

This allows me to simplify `foo` into `foo(struct Bar bar, ...) { ... }`, which is great. But when I do this the execution time goes from 1m35 to 2m18, which is a slowdown 45%. Using pointers instead, like `foo(struct Bar* bar, ...)` is faster at 2m03, but still slower overall. All of these measurements were taken with `gcc 12.2.0`. I compiled an optimized build (`-O3`).

I understand that adding a layer of indirection is bound to slow the program down, but given that this is such a [common pattern](http://wiki.c2.com/?ParameterObject) and the change is so slight, I expected that the compiler would optimize this indirection away.

I also wonder if there is anything I can do to tell the compiler what I'm doing. Kind of like how `inline` can be used to change how functions are compiled. If nothing else, I'm curious as to why this is apparently a hard thing for the compiler to recognize and optimize.

Thank you in advance!

P.S. Here's the full code, it's short enough to put here. It's before I added the struct and it finds a solution to the [N queens problem on the torus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eight_queens_puzzle#Related_problems). The three arrays I'm trying to put into a struct are `cols, updiags, downdiags`.

```c
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define N 31

int upDiag(int row, int col) {
    int updiag = row + col;
    if (updiag >= N)
        updiag -= N;
    return updiag;
}

int downDiag(int row, int col) {
    int downdiag = row - col;
    if (downdiag < 0)
        downdiag += N;
    return downdiag;
}

bool isSafeTorus(int* cols, int* updiags, int* downdiags, int row, int col, int updiag, int downdiag){

    for(int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
        if (cols[i] == col || updiags[i] == updiag || downdiags[i] == downdiag) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

bool solveNQUtil(int* cols, int* updiags, int* downdiags, int row){
    /* If all queens are placed then return true */
    if (row >= N)
        return true;
    /* try placing this queen in all coloms one by one */
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        /* Check if the queen can be placed on board[row][i] */
        int updiag = upDiag(row, i);
        int downdiag = downDiag(row, i);

        if (isSafeTorus(cols, updiags, downdiags, row, i, updiag, downdiag)) {
            cols[row] = i;
            updiags[row] = updiag;
            downdiags[row] = downdiag;
            /* place rest of queens */
            if (solveNQUtil(cols, updiags, downdiags, row + 1))
                return true;
            /* If placing queen in board[i][col] no solution, remove queen*/
        }
    }
    /* Queen can not be placed this row */
    return false;
}


void main(){
    int* cols = (int*)malloc(N * sizeof(int));
    int* updiags = (int*)malloc(N * sizeof(int));
    int* downdiags = (int*)malloc(N * sizeof(int));

    if (solveNQUtil(cols, updiags, downdiags, 0) == false) {
        printf("Solution does not exist");
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        printf("%d\n", cols[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: do not cast the result of malloc and use objects not types in `sizeof`s `int* cols = malloc(N * sizeof(*cols));`

Comment: Does struct simplify? If you want to pass only one pointer allocate 3*N array and simply modify indexes to access the particular arrays.

Comment: Or use a 2D array, and pass a (correctly typed) pointer to its first element.  Then you don't even need special index computations.  And having all the arrays contiguous in memory could give you a performance improvement, too, especially if you choose the right order of the dimensions.

Comment: @0___________, I could do that (one 3N array), but that seems like I would simply move the messiness I'm trying to get rid of from the function signature to the points where I access the array.

EDIT: a 2D array would work, although then I can't name the individual things.

Comment: Re naming: you could use macros to name the index values corresponding to the three logically distinct 1D arrays.  That would assist with code clarity.

Comment: @JohnBollinger That's actually a really good idea, and a good use for macros.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: I tried that already and do not see any significant improvement. Also, memory arrangement is largely irrelevant for three 31-`int` arrays; it fits in cache and does not thrash.

Comment: I still think that it's cleaner since it makes the function signatures shorter

Comment: @EricPostpischil, the main point of a 2D array w/ macros is not to improve performance relative to the orginal code.  It is to provide *clearer* code relative to a single 1D array containing all the data.  And the reason for either one of those is to reduce the number of distinct parameters to some of the functions, as an alternative to putting three distinct pointers into a structure.  If the one-array approach achieves performance similar to the original code then that's a success.

Comment: @Trashtalk, I do not replicate the performance issue you report for the alternative of putting the three distinct pointers into a struct, and passing the struct by value.  In fact, I see a consistent, but very small (< 2%), performance improvement with that, relative to your original code.  This is with GCC 8.5.0 on Linux, optimizing at the -O3 level.  And performance similar to the original is indeed what I would have predicted for that.

Comment: I speculate that the performance degradation you observed may have been the result of different optimization settings, rather than of code differences.  For example, switching from `-O3` to just `-O` gives me about a 30% performance degradation on your code (with GCC 8.5.0 / Linux x86_64).  That's the right order of magnitude for the difference you observed.